# how to submit a formik form through mutation with ApolloClient?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, antd, apollo-client, formik

i have create a sample Formik form using antd. Now iam adding mutation with POST_MUTATION.How to submit form values through formik. Here i called handleSubmit with in the form.But it is not called?

```
 import React from 'react'
import { Formik, Field, Form } from 'formik';
import * as AntD from "antd";
import TextField from "./shared/TextField"
import { Mutation, graphql } from 'react-apollo'
import gql from 'graphql-tag'
import data from './shared/data'

const POST_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation PostMutation($username: String!, $email: String!, $password: String!){
    post(username: $username, email: $email, password: $password) {

      username
      email
      password
    }
  }
`


class FormikApollo extends React.Component {
  state = {
      username: '',
      email: '',
      password: '',
      data: {}
  }

  handleChange= (e) => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name] : e.target.value,
            data
        })
  }

  handleSubmit = () => {
   alert("called")
  }
```

And i add my formik form using this way.Now i want to submit the form values  these are not submitted.How to Submit the form values in formik?

```
form = props => {
            const { username, email, password  } = this.state;
            return (
                <div align="center">
                    <h3 align="center">Registration Form</h3>
                    <Mutation mutation={POST_MUTATION} variables={{ username, email, password }}>
                    { postMutation  => (
                    <Form onSubmit={(formikValues) => postMutation({ variables: formikValues })}>
                        <Row gutter={4}>
                            <Col span={12} push={5}>
                                <Field
                                    name="username"
                                    label="Name"
                                    placeholder="Enter a Name"
                                    component={TextField}
                                    formitemlayout={formItemLayout} 
                                    value={this.state.username}
                                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                                    />

                                <Field
                                    name="email"
                                    label="Email"
                                    placeholder="Enter an Email"
                                    component={TextField}
                                    formitemlayout={formItemLayout} 
                                    value={this.state.email}
                                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                                    />

                                <Field
                                    name="password"
                                    label="Password"
                                    type="password"
                                    placeholder="Enter a Password"
                                    component={TextField}
                                    formitemlayout={formItemLayout} 
                                    value={this.state.password}
                                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                                  />


                                 <Button type="submit" onClick={JSON.stringify(postMutation)}>Submit</Button>


                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                    </Form>
                    )}

                    </Mutation>
                </div>
            )
        }


        render() {

            return (
                <div align="center">
                    <Formik
                        initialValues = {{
                          username: '',
                          email:'',
                          password:''
                        }}
                        render={this.form}
                    />

                </div>
            )
        }

    }

    export default FormikApollo
```

Answer (score 1):

your approach is correct. It is better to wrap the whole component into mutation and use it as to render props.
This is a simple register component. I am using typescript if you find some syntax  hard to follow.

Working example with ant-design and graphql(Typescript): [`https://github.com/benawad/graphql-typescript-stripe-example`](https://github.com/benawad/graphql-typescript-stripe-example)

Youtube Series: [`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G-Kj8Re6spA&list=PLN3n1USn4xllF5t1GZhEwFQNDnStgupdB`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G-Kj8Re6spA&list=PLN3n1USn4xllF5t1GZhEwFQNDnStgupdB)

```
import { Field, Formik } from "formik";
import React from "react";
import Layout from "../components/Layout";

import { RegisterMutationVariables, RegisterMutation } from "../../schemaTypes";

const registerMutation = gql`
  mutation RegisterMutation($email: String!, $password: String!) {
    register(email: $email, password: $password)
  }
`;

export default () => {
  return (
    <Layout title="Register page">
      <Mutation<RegisterMutation, RegisterMutationVariables>
        mutation={registerMutation}
      >
        {register => (
          <Formik
            validateOnBlur={false}
            validateOnChange={false}
            onSubmit={async (data, { setErrors }) => {
              try {
                const response = await register({
                  variables: {
                    data
                  }
                });
                console.log(response);
              } catch (err) {
                console.log(err)
              }
            }}
            initialValues={{
              email: "",
              password: ""
            }}
          >
            {({ handleSubmit }) => (
              <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <Field
                  name="email"
                  placeholder="email"
                  component={InputField}
                />
                <Field
                  name="password"
                  placeholder="password"
                  type="password"
                  component={InputField}
                />
                <button type="submit">submit</button>
              </form>
            )}
          </Formik>
        )}
      </Mutation>
    </Layout>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the code formatting makes it a bit difficult to see your code, however, in general you could put the form inside the mutation and use the mutation function as the submit function of the form like so:

```
<Form onSubmit={(formikValues) => postMutation({ variables: formikValues })}>
```

Comment: i have tried to call a form inside a mutation and also called the onSubmit={(formikValues) => postMutation({ variables: formikValues })} but form is not submitted

Comment: Would you mind updating your post with the code you used?

Comment: Code seems fine to me. I think you should set up a sandbox. https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: but antd was not applied to formik form in sandbox code but my original form was applied for antd

Answer (score 0):

I took a  different approach using both *formik* and *apollo mutation*.
Instead of using another tag of Mutation (so sick of them btw! make your code look dirty so fast), i used **this.props.mutate()** in a function.

Your mutation can be found in the props when you export your component with that mutation under the influence of graphql. You will see it in a bit.

This is how my form looks like, inside my component's main render() function

```js
< Formik
initialValues = {
  {
    title: '',
  }
}
onSubmit = {
  this.submitMutation // my own function
}
render = {
  this.renderForm // my own function that just returns views and texts tags
}
validationSchema = {
    Yup.object().shape({
      title: Yup
        .string()
        .required('title is required'),
    })
  } >

  <
  /Formik>
```

Below is my submit mutation function that gets called by the formik

```js
submitMutation = () => {
  return this.props.mutate({
    variables: {
      title: this.state.title,
    },
  })
}
```

And at the end do this

```js
export default graphql(addBillMutation)(CreateBill);
```

OverAll Code..please adjust it to your suit

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet, Text, Image, View, TextInput, Picker, TouchableOpacity, ScrollView, KeyboardAvoidingView
} from 'react-native';

import Header from './header';
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';
//import mutation query from queries
import { getBillsQuery, addBillMutation } from './queries/queries';
import { Formik } from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup';

class CreateBill extends React.Component<any, any>  {
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            title: "",
            loading: false,
        }
        this.submitMutation = this.submitMutation.bind(this);
    }

    submitMutation = () => {
        return this.props.mutate({
            variables: {
                title: this.state.title,
            }
        })
    }

    _handleSubmit = async (values: any) => {
        //setting values here, when form is already validated by yup in formika
        this.setState({
            title: values.title,
        });
        try {
            //set loading to true before sending request
            this.setState({ loading: true });
            await this.submitMutation()
                .then(({ data }) => {
                  //response handling
                }).catch((error) => {
                    this.setState({ loading: false });
                    //error handling
                });
        } catch (error) {
            //handle error
        }
    }

    renderForm = (formikProps: any) => {
        const {
            values, handleSubmit, handleBlur, handleChange, errors,
            touched, isValid, isSubmitting
        } = formikProps;

        return (

                <ScrollView>
                            <View>
                                        <TextInput
                                            style={styles.input}
                                            value={values.title}
                                            placeholder="title goes here"
                                            onChangeText={handleChange('title')}
                                            onBlur={handleBlur('title')}
                                        />
                                    </View>
                                        {(touched.title && errors.title) ? touched.title && errors.title : "Required"}
                                    </Text>
                                </View>
                                        
                            </View>
                </ScrollView>
        );
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Header />
                <View>

                    <Formik
                        initialValues={{ title: ''}}
                        onSubmit={this._handleSubmit}
                        render={this.renderForm}
                        validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
                            title: Yup
                                .string()
                                .required('title is required'),
                        })}
                    >

                    </Formik>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default graphql(addBillMutation)(CreateBill);
```